# Can I adding files and import comment to archive by a command line

Tags: command-line, rar, comments

I use below commend to add the file to the archiver and add data recovery recorder on linux os

rar a -m0 -hp"$password" -v1073741824b -rr3 -ep1 test1.rar test

If I want to add the comment from the file - comment, can I edit the above command line to realize it.

btw: I know I can add another command like "rar c -zcomment test.part1.rar" to add the comment from the content of "comment" file into volume 1 of test1.rar, but the side effect is it will also lose the recovery recorder and change the file size ( may less then 1073741824 bit) of the volume 1, so I hope I can add the comment and compress the file at the same time by one one commend line, please provide me some suggestion....thanks

goddesschi

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your pseudo-English, but if you want to do it in one line try this:

*rar a -c -zyourcomment.txt -m5  -hp"$password" -v1073741824b -rr3p -ep1 test1.rar test*